# TCP Established connection spike in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, tcp

We are using AWS ELB in HTTP mode and are observing a spike in TCP established connection on Tomcat server. We have Apache HTTP server with mod_proxy between ELB and Tomcat.
Apache and Tomcat run on same AWS instance. SSL is terminated at ELB and sessions are sticky.
Apache has 150 workers and tomcat has 200 max threads. Established connection count is going up to 650!

We see ELB IP as remote IP when using netstat from app server machine.
We can see remote IP in X-Forwarded-For header in access log, but those are the requests we successfully processed and those may not be the ones causing TCP flood.

AWS support says that there is no way of monitoring TCP connections at ELB except CloudWatch, ELB Access Logs or CloudTrail.
ELB Access logs will show us the remote IP but it also logs only completed requests.

Any help/pointer on this is appreciated.

Thanks,
Sameer

Comment: *"ELB Access logs will show us the remote IP but it also logs only completed requests."*  That is essentially untrue.  Any request that is sent to your instance will succeed, fail, or time out, and all of these are logged by ELB.  Only incoming connections that don't result in anything ever being sent to your instance *might* not be logged, but these cannot possibly be what you are seeing at the instance, by definition. If it reaches your instance through ELB, it's logged. Have you examined the ELB logs?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot We had one more incident today. ESTA connections went from ~60 to ~740 on each of 4 Apache instances in one minute! We had enabled ELB logs and #of hits in ELB logs were 610,705 vs. in tomcat logs 599,142 for that one hour. Since ELB logs completion time, the HTTP request must fully complete. I am sure that not all those 720 ESTA TCP connections resulted in completed HTTP requests, hence we don't know where those additional requests came from.

Comment: *We had enabled ELB logs and #of hits in ELB logs were 610,705 vs. in tomcat logs 599,142 for that one hour.* ELB logged *more* requests than your app. Doesn't that clearly disprove a fundamental aspect of your assertion?  ELB logs "completion" time, yes, but you seem to overlook the fact that *ELB requests can "complete" by failing*.  An error or an ELB-imposed timeout (60 seconds, by default) is still a *completed* request.   An ELB request that arrives while all instances are out of service is still a *completed* request, and is still logged (as a 503).

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Completely agree with you on "ELB can respond with failure when backend instances are unreachable or time out". That is why there are two status codes in ELB access log.

Comment: The point: `backend-ip:port` is in the ELB access logs, and *any* connection the ELB made to your machine *should* be in the logs, whether a request "completed" (by any definition ou prefer) or not.  These should correlate to what you see.  Docs: *"[ELB] logs all requests sent to the load balancer, including requests that never made it to the back-end instances. For example, if a client sends a malformed request, or there are no healthy instances to respond, the requests are still logged."* http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/access-log-collection.html